# MSAccess- Changes to linked table (View) not saved

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have an MS-Access front end to a MSSQL server back end. The existing, functional updates that the tool makes are applied through a MSSQL view which is inserted to MS-Access as a linked table. There is a primary key defined for this linked 'table' (view).

The user sees a subset of records that match previously selected criteria, and uses comboboxes (unbound) to select the value of several fields that are then applied to all matching records using `DoCmd.RunSQL` with `Me.Filter` on the "After Update" Event.

Users have requested an additional piece of functionality.

I have:

1. Added the new column required to the underlying table referenced in the view
2. Added the column to be output in the view
3. Refreshed the linked table in MS-Access
4. Added the new field to the form that will be updating it, and modified the `DoCmd.RunSQL` statement to enact the `UPDATE`

When updating the new field via the form, I get the standard message `"You are about to change x rows"` where x is the appropriate number. Pressing OK gives no errors, but the table is not updated.

To debug, I attempted to change the record in the linked table view directly. Again no errors were thrown, and the row seems to be updated, but this is not reflected in SSMS, and reloading the table in MS-Access the change is no longer present. I can change the values of columns other than the new one.

I also tested adding the underlying table as a linked table and I can edit the rows in MS-Access in this table.

(Update)
At @ErikvonAsmuth suggestion below I tried using Recordsets on the bound form instead of the `DoCmd.RunSQL`. Again could access the record and an update gave no error on `rst.Update`, but the change is not reflected in the database for the new field. I can change a previously existing field using this method as above.
Seems my problem is independent of the update method.
(/Update)

I would appreciate any ideas for next steps to check.

Comment: Usually, forms are bound, and not using `DoCmd.RunSQL` to execute updates. You should try either binding your form, using recordsets, or using passthrough queries to execute the update directly on SQL server.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Erik, unfortunately getting the same behaviour. Updated question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

There was a trigger defined on the view to handle saving to the table. I altered this in SSQL to add the new column and everything is working now.

Found a hint when I tried to edit the field in SSMS and it wouldn't work there either - was getting a `Row failed to retrieve on last operation` error.

That lead me to a thread referencing triggers on [ExpertsExchange](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28546681/Sql-server-is-not-committing-row.html)

I will be going back and changing the `DoCMD.RunSQL` statements to use recordsets.